# How to sign up a new shell without root authority?

Tags: bash, zsh

1. The directory '/etc/shells' which I can not modify doesn't contain the zsh shell directory in my own directory.
2. I'm already make zsh installed using the zsh.tar.gz baggage because I do not own root authority.
3. But when I tried to install Oh-My-Zsh via Curl and Wget , I've encountered the following issues: **zsh is not installed**.
4. How can I install Oh-My-Zsh without root?

Comment: Did you include the directory you used to install zsh at #2 to your PATH?

Comment: yes,I 've included install directory '../bin/' to my PATH. I'm able to use zsh commend to run zsh shell

Comment: Assuming you're using [this link](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), the `install.sh` file is hard-wired to check /etc/shells - specifically it evaluates `CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED=$(grep /zsh$ /etc/shells | wc -l)`. So as far as I can see you will either need to edit that script to suppress the check (rather than just passing it directly to `sh`), or use the **Manual Installation** option given at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, but the Manual Installation option seems to use chsh commend which refers to '/etc/shells' without zsh path . But I will try this and the first way (to modify install.sh file)

Comment: Well regardless of whether or not you install oh-my-zsh, you won't be able to set zsh as your *login* shell if it's not listed in /etc/shells - the best you will be able to do is start zsh from your .profile - but that's really a separate issue, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the oh-my-zsh github website and find file named as 'install.sh'.
2. Download the file and open it with a text editor ( or use wget command ) .
3. Delete the code line like this: CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED=$(grep ......
4. Save changes.
5. Try to run the file and it will be ok.